# Using List<string> to dynamically write a file: formatting issue

Tags: c#, string, list

I've written a function which will let me to dynamically write a file containing some code. I'm feeding the method the number of points. I've nailed it, but I'm having a stupid formatting issue.

The following code (with `numberOfPoints = 3`)

```
private static void PointsGenerator(int numberOfPoints)
{
    string fileContent = Resources.Points_AutoGenerated;
    List<string> lines = new List<string>(fileContent.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None));

    for (var j = 0; j < numberOfPoints - 1; j++)
    {
        int index = 0;

        for (var i = 1; !lines[i].Equals("ENDMODULE"); i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Contains("! <<< POINT PLACEHOLDER >>>"))
            {
                if (numberOfPoints == 1)
                {
                    // Let's remove the placeholder...
                    lines.RemoveAt(i);

                    // ... and the extra new-line.
                    lines.RemoveAt(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    lines.RemoveAt(i);
                    lines.Insert(i, Resources.Snippet_POINT);
                    index = i;
                }
            }
        }

        if (j < numberOfPoints - 2)
        {
            lines.Insert(index + 2, "! <<< POINT PLACEHOLDER >>>");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray()));
}
```

is outputting this file

```
! <<< Code generated with MG ABB Missions Generator. >>>

MODULE Points_AutoGenerated

    TASK PERS robtarget pPointX := [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9]];

    TASK PERS robtarget pPointY := [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9]];

    TASK PERS robtarget pPointY := [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9]];
ENDMODULE
```

I don't like it 'cause I'm missing an extra new-line before of the `ENDMODULE` line.

But if I use this second code (just pasting the part I've changed)

```
if (j < numberOfPoints - 2)
{
    lines.Insert(index + 2, "! <<< POINT PLACEHOLDER >>>");
}
    else
{
    lines.Insert(index + 1, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I'm getting this output, instead

```
! <<< Code generated with MG ABB Missions Generator. >>>

MODULE Points_AutoGenerated

    TASK PERS robtarget pPointX := [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9]];

    TASK PERS robtarget pPointY := [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9]];

    TASK PERS robtarget pPointY := [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9]];


ENDMODULE
```

which, similarly to before, I don't like because of the extra new-line at the end (I just want one of them!).

What am I missing out?

Those are the the two templates I'm using to generate the final file:

**Points_AutoGenerated.txt**

```
! <<< Code generated with MG ABB Missions Generator. >>>

MODULE Points_AutoGenerated

    TASK PERS robtarget pPointX := [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9]];

    ! <<< POINT PLACEHOLDER >>>

ENDMODULE
```

and **Snippet_POINT.txt**

```
    TASK PERS robtarget pPointY := [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9, 9E9]];
```

Comment: you are trying to remove empty lines? i don't get what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: I was trying to have a new empty line after every line of code. boommelding helped me to sort out the issue in my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just  add an empty string, you already get a newline from your WriteLine(Join()) .

```
else
{
    lines.Insert(index + 1, "");
}

// here the empty string becomes an empty line
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray()));
```

Comment: Damn, like I thought it was a pretty stupid issue. I've used `string.Empty`. Thank you so much.

Comment: Due to string interning, `string.Empty == ""` in every way. Pick what you like to read.